# Unable to login in fedora 16

Tags: fedora, login

I install the fedora 16 but I skipped to create at least one user account during installation. Now I am unable to log in to the Fedora graphical environment. How can I create log in account?

Comment: Does login in tty works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-start in single user mode and then create a new user account.

Comment: You will have to run `useradd` (see its manpage) to create the user.